# How do you get individual borders to show on ie 8?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get a project to work on ie8, however I cant find anything wrong with the following styles, from doing research it seems that ie8 should be able to pick up all these styles the styles work in chrome perfectly fine.

Thank you in advance

```
 .tabs a.tab {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-right: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
  color: #999999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Yep, IE8 should work fine with those border styles. Can't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't. Can you show us a demo of the problem? (eg using jsBin.com)

Comment: I sure can, thanks for your response I will post one shortly

Comment: IE8 may have problems with `display: table-cell`. Are you simulating an entire table (with this element being in a parent with `display: table-row` and so on) or is this a solitary table-cell?